# Php menu with GET

Tags: php

I have a switch menu so my pages are called into index.php and then loads the page content from whatever is on the file so I am having to only use the includes files once throughout - I am having an issue though with a link to in my case a single product page view. So the url will be appended with something like `products_single.php?prod_id=46` But the way my menus are set it does not recognise this as a valid url as far as I can see?

Here is the function which creates the link:

```
function settings_layout($page_id) {

    switch($page_id) {

        default: 
            echo '<p class="red">Whoops! this page does not exist!</p>';
        case '':


        // PRODUCTS      
         case 'products_single':
            include_once("modules/products/products_single.php");
            break;           
       }
   }
```

To get to the page `products_single` that query lives in the `build_prod_list()` which basically just lists out the products from the products table. The name of the product is wrapped in a link `a href="index.php?page=products_single?prod_id='.$row["prod_id"].'"> '.$row["prod_name"]. '</a>` Where this is sat in a while loop inside of the `build_prod_list()` function.

So as a function I which I am calling `build_prods_single()` grabs the product data from the database and shows it on `products_single.php`

so when the link is clicked the url is `index.php?page=products_single?prod_id=46` but shows the error 'Whoops! this page does not exist!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `&` ampersand between products_single and prod_id

```
<a href="index.php?page=products_single&prod_id='.$row["prod_id"].'"> '.$row["prod_name"]. '</a>
```